# Add multiple possible options in a Slash-Command

Tags: java, discord, command, discord-jda

I've got the following Problem:

I am trying to implement one Discord Slash-Command with the JDA that can be entered like this:

```
/user @User
```

or like this:

```
/user 277048745458401282
```

But you should be required to use one of the Options.

I currently have a **/user** Slash-Command with a **USER** OptionType, but my Question would be how I could add another Option to it, but you have to only choose one of the 2 Options.

This is my current code:

```
List<CommandData> cmds = new ArrayList<CommandData>();

cmds.add(new CommandData("user", "Shows information about a specific Discord User.")
                    .addOption(OptionType.USER, "user", "The user you want to get the information from."));

jda.getGuildById(712313516542918717L).updateCommands().addCommands(cmds).queue();
```

Comment: The OptionType user accepts user ids too. You can just paste the id in the client.

Comment: Thank you, that worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **[Minn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10630900/minn)** for answering in the Comments.

> The OptionType user accepts user ids too. You can just paste the id in the client.

This worked for me :D